# If statement with negative return

Tags: c#

For some reason this does not look correct. Is there a better way to write/refractor this?

```
if (!(auth.DoesAuthMatch && auth.DoesEmailMatch))
{
    statusText = "Access Denied";
}
```

I think I have a 'case of the Mondays!..'

Comment: DeMorgan's laws: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws

Comment: always look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Refactor to a method:

```
private bool IsAccessDenied(Auth auth)
{
    return !(auth.DoesAuthMatch && auth.DoesEmailMatch);
}

if (IsAccessDenied(auth))
{
    statusText = "Access Denied";
}
```

As for the Boolean logic:

```
!(auth.DoesAuthMatch && auth.DoesEmailMatch) == 
(!auth.DoesAuthMatch || !auth.DoesEmailMatch)
```

A simple application of [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Why should it be refactored to a method?

Comment: @siride: So that you must chase down the called method just to see what the code does. Although the logic is clear, trying to understand the code is harder in my view.

Comment: I chose @Oded as it shows examples PLUS other solutions and a link to a resource. All of the responses were about the same, just slight variations. I used 

`(!(auth.DoesAuthMatch && auth.DoesEmailMatch))`

Thanks for everyone's response early on a Monday.

Comment: @JonathanWood: yes, it just seems unnecessary for such a simple piece of logic. Certainly several lines of auth-checking code, reused throughout a project should be in a single method, but not this.

Comment: @siride - Readability is also a factor. There is now a function with a descriptive name explaining the _what_ of the function, in case the _how_ changes in the future.

Comment: @Oded: I don't think this little example is good place to apply that principle. A simple boolean test is not worth encapsulating. If it should become more complicated, then it can be refactored. Otherwise, you have code littered with tiny functions that, in aggregate, become incomprehensible, thus reducing readability.

Answer (score 2):

It is fine - the equivalent would be :

```
if (!auth.DoesAuthMatch || !auth.DoesEmailMatch)
{
    statusText = "Access Denied";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code looks right. But may be a bit more readable as:

```
if (!auth.DoesAuthMatch || !auth.DoesEmailMatch)
```

Or maybe even:

```
if (auth.DoesAuthMatch == false || auth.DoesEmailMatch == false)
```

Comment: @Oded: Did you have a reason for that, or are you just being dogmatic?

Comment: I find such constructs to be redundant and less readable. Call it a matter of style if you will.

Comment: It is a matter of style. However, looking at my examples above, I personally find that the clearest version of the two.

Comment: @JonathanWood: but if you read it out load, the one with `!` sounds better. It's easy for me to say and parse "if not auth.DoesAuthMatch" than "if auth.DoesAuthMatch equals false". Still a matter of style, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just inverting it? I find that positive logic is quicker to understand when reading code.

e.g.:

```
if (auth.DoesAuthMatch && auth.DoesEmailMatch)
{     
    statusText = "Access Granted"; 
}
else
{
    statusText = "Access Denied";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could change it to...

```
if (!auth.DoesAuthMatch || !auth.DoesEmailMatch) statusText = "Access Denied";
```